# Execute psexec and output to file on localhost

Tags: java, command-line, groovy, processbuilder, psexec

I have a problem with psexec running from java , following are my test script :

```
def cmd = 'psexec.exe \\\\IP_ADRESS -accepteula -u "user_name" -p "passwd" net start MyService > C:/output.txt 2>&1'
def proc = cmd.execute()
proc.waitFor();
```

As you know , I want start MyService from remote machine ,and output stdout to local machine in `C:/output`
After I running the script , no file output , nothing showing on script console

I tried to googling but no luck :(

Certainly , I can run above command from command-line

```
psexec.exe \\IP_ADRESS -accepteula -u "user_name" -p "passwd" net start MyService > C:/output.txt 2>&1
```

So , what the matter with my script ?

And I have another question

When I run this command from command-line

```
psexec.exe \\IP_ADRESS -accepteula -u "user_name" -p "passwd" net start MyService > C:/output.txt 2>&1`
```

I get output in `C:/output.txt` :

```
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
The MyService started.
Connecting to 10.0.0.2...
Starting PsExec service on 10.0.0.2...
Connecting with PsExec service on 10.0.0.2...
Starting net on 10.0.0.2...
net exited on 10.0.0.2 with error code 0.
```

I only want this string `The MyService started.` output to file , not something like message from PSEXEC

How can I do that ?,any illegal about copyright ? Please help me

Many thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

i dont know about windows, but redirection of stdout/err, like you are planing there, might be a shell feature.  If you are only interested in the resulting output (and not the file itself), you can access stdin/out on your `proc` variable.

from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy :

```
def command = """executable arg1 arg2 arg3"""// Create the String
def proc = command.execute()                 // Call *execute* on the string
proc.waitFor()                               // Wait for the command to finish
println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}" // *out* from the external program is *in* for groovy
```

also be sure to check the error code and the stderr for the actual errors.  if in doubt, instead of `'cmd arg1 arg2'.execute()` consider running `['cmd','arg1','arg2'].execute()` if your application there is picky.

Comment: Thanks , but I need to output stdout/err to file because sometime I run a script or application , process hangs or exit without return stdout from that script/app

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with java and psexec. I wasn't getting the output from psexec back in java. I found this alternative to use [paexec](http://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/) on the gradle forum:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/exec_starting_remote_process_with_psexec_does_not_return_on_windows.

paexec is very similar to psexec and has some added features. Looks like another added feature is the ability to get output back in java.

Comment: "The page you requested doesn't exist or is private". You should include a code sample in your answer if possible.